# What are the consecuences of using a false name when using a valid credit card on the internet?

Tags: credit-card

I have an Android device and I always use a false gmail account for all the Android related services (meaning a gmail account which does not give clues about my **real name**) .

For obvious reasons I don't want Alphabet to associate my real name to that device's usage. This has worked for a few months but now I would like to purchase an app which is not free on **Google Play**.

The only payment method seems to be **credit card**. I have a credit card, I would give them all the relevant data (Number, expiration date, vc...) but a false name.

Is this possible? Will they receive the real name anyway?

Comment: This is not really a security question, but a payment processing question. You might need to ask your credit card issuer or Google support. In the past, I have been able to use a mistyped name (by mistake) but some card issuers require the exact name on the card (punctuation and all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two related questions here.

**Can the merchant charge your card given an invalid name field?**

*In general*, yes.  Name validation is usually not turned on by default, so from a card processing point of view the name you gave is stored at the processor, but not passed on to the card brands during authorization.

If Name Validation is turned on (or if your merchant is using [Address Verification](https://merch.bankofamerica.com/documents/10162/12961/Merchant+Guide+to+AVS.pdf)), they may decline your transaction if you provide invalid name (or address) information.

So, assuming no validation, the processor will store whatever name you gave, and associate it with your charge records which are available to the merchant.  So long as you're consistent in presenting the same fake name, that's all they'll see.

**Can the merchant request your name given your valid card number?**

Essentially, no.  Card-brand-to-processor-to-merchant data flows like [Account Updater](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/visa-account-updater-product-information-fact-sheet-for-merchants.pdf) don't include the cardholder name.  I'm not aware of any API to allow merchants or processors to query this information.  It's not part of the standard card data flow.

I'm hesitant to say it's impossible, however... your issuing bank, obviously, knows the name on the card.  And it's not unthinkable that the merchant might fax a request for clarification of that information with some hand-waving about potential fraud and get a response which includes your cardholder name.  And if Law Enforcement ever gets involved, they'll have your full account info in two shakes of a lambs tail.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to color @gowenfawr's useful answer.

In terms of risk, even without Name Validation turned on, transaction data- the provided card number, name, purchase details, geolocation, and other information- is often nevertheless made available to fraud processing services, enabling reputation scoring can be done on individual card numbers.

Google does a big enough business that it would be very unlikely for them not to use and contribute to fraud scoring. The fact that a name is used that doesn't match the source of truth for the card number can be a signal that the card is being fraudulently employed. Even if transactions are not immediately rejected it may lead to a fraud determination and a rejection later on. So even if transactions are approved with incorrect name information, there is some future risk.

Also, in the context of whether Google/Alphabet has the ability to match a real name with a particular device- I am sorry to say that there are uncountably many ways to do that. To list just 3:

- Names mentioned in the contents of the email the "fake" email address sends and receives can obviously be associated with the email address and disambiguated to relate more to the sender, recipient, or third party.
- Presumably the device is not using cell networks- accounts for which are of course associated with real identity data at least in the US- but the mapping of wifi networks to physical addresses is pervasive, and the names associated with physical addresses are generally public information.
- Should another device you use have visibility to real name information, the use of common web sites or other services across the "real" and the "fake" device identities can be processed as a disambiguating signal, even if one doesn't have or explicitly utilize credentials in common across devices. There are many ways in which the custodian of the "real" data may legitimately share it with others in the context of their published privacy policy.